# Asp.Net MVC 5 Model binding for child ICollection property is null on HTTPPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a code first MVC 5 application. My data models are having virtual **ICollection** properties to achieve one to many relations. The problem is on form submit the ICollection type list of entities are received as null in the controller.

Following is a sample code for your reference:

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<City> Cities{ get; set; }
}
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class StateViewModel
{
    *<other properties>*
    public List<State> States{ get; set; }
}
```

Let say the requirement is to show the list of States and the list of its Cities underneath. The Cities name should be displayed in a Text box so that user can edit them inline. The problem I am facing is - on submit the Cities under StateViewModel.States are received as null.

Here is how my view looks like:

```
  @for (int index = 0; index < Model.States.Count(); index++)
    {
        Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.States[index].Id);
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < Model.States[index].Cities.Count(); index2++)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.States[index].Cities.ElementAt(index2).Name)
            Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.States[index].Cities.ElementAt(index2).Id);
            <br />
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody came here looking for an answer, this worked for me:

```
@Html.TextBox("States[" + index + "].Cities[" + index2 + "].Name", Model.States[index].Cities.ElementAt(index2).Name)
```